# OBDII Which hardware and software allows scripting via unix terminal

Tags: can, obd

I developed an embedded design with dsPIC processor, which is a remote start module, communicating via 6 CAN busses.

Often I would need a much quicker, simpler solution to test something on CAN bus, without writing compilable program.

I need an Unix terminal scripting capability, plus a compatible hardware OBD interface (USB or wireless), one CAN channel suffice, more is better.

Anybody can recommend such a combination?

Comment: USB to CAN or PCI/e to CAN interfaces are available, but there may or may not be drivers for Unix type OS. If not, you may end up having to go with a PC with Windows, for that Unix type scripting can be added through MinGW (or Cygwin). I don't know if that would be good enough for you. A PC/Windows system should have no problem getting a compatible OBD interface in similar ways.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that will be my plan B in case I fail finding Unix device